# axios not sending cookie to nestjs from NextJs

Tags: axios, next.js, nestjs

Have a front end nextJs running on a different port to the backend nestjs.

Within the nextJs session-cookie I have 2 JWT tokens access and refresh.
I can extract the access token from the next-auth session-token but axios will not send to nestjs.

If I use the { withCredentials: true } the whole next-auth token is sent but if I use the headers object nothing is received

```
const data = await axios.post(
            process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SH_API_BASEURL + '/blog',
            { formData },
            //{ withCredentials: true }
            {
                headers: {
                    Cookie:
                        'Authentication=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjEzNTQ1N2FiLWI4MGUtNDU2OC1hY2RiLWNiODZmYTJlNGQxMyIsImlhdCI6MTY1MzU0NjM0NiwiZXhwIjoxNjU0NDQ2MzQ2fQ.fvnRXYwheuIOHvlTZRGqBiVR98JxdT7UqZbc6SAvcAk; Path=/; HttpOnly;'
                },
            }
        );
```

nestJS - log when using with credentials

```
{
 'next-auth.csrf-token':   '493deccd24c0165f8afe08db04352415c46c7a6f150f9c51320aea0d5444589d|51953c1c056c986b799afb9dcea8c94469d35b4aab291b02ee343057fa80a70e',
'next-auth.callback-url': 'http://localhost:3000/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http://localhost:3000/',
'next-auth.session-token': 'eyJhbGc
}
```

But if use the headers I get

```
[Object: null prototype] {}
```

The nestJs logging is done using:

```
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
    (request: Request) => {
      console.log('JWT strategy auth cookie');
      console.log(request?.cookies);

      return request?.cookies?.Authentication;
    },
  ]),
```

If I make a call from postman there is no issue with processing the header cookie.

Could you let me know how to get axios to send the header cookie only?

Thanks

Comment: hello Chris did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: No I need to extract nestJs token  from nextAuth token . If I set withCredentials:true the nextAuth token is sent.